# An issue with vectorising Gsub

Tags: r, function, for-loop, text-mining, gsub

**Aim:**
I am a newcomer to `R`, but I am trying to familiarise myself with programming in `R`. In a current task, I wanted to replace a number of words occurring in a `corpus` whilst keeping in tact the structure of the `corpus`.

`Gsub` did not allow vectors to be used for patterns and corresponding replacements, so I decided to write a modified `Gsub` function. (*I am aware of the `Gsubfn` function, but I would like to develop some programming skills too.*)

**Data Generation**

```
a<- c("this is a testOne","this is testTwo","this is testThree","this is testFour")
corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(a))
pattern1<- c("testOne","testTwo","testThree")
replacement1<- c("gameOne","gameTwo","gameThree")
```

**Modified Gsub**

```
gsub2<- function(myPattern, myReplacement, myCorpus, fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=FALSE){
for (i in 1:length(myCorpus)){
    for (j in 1:length(myPattern)){
    myCorpus[[i]]<- gsub(myPattern[j],myReplacement[j], myCorpus[[i]], fixed=TRUE)
    }
}
}
```

**Code Execution**

```
gsub2(pattern1,replacement1,corpus,fixed=TRUE)
```

However, no change is produced in the actual corpus. I think it is because all the changes are being made within the function, and thus, are limited to within the function. And then I tried returning the corpus but `R` fails to recognise the corpus object.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?
Thanks.

Comment: In R terms Your function needs to return `myCorpus` after both loops have finished, then you would need assign the results of the function to an object. See `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package to see an alternative to your approach above.

Comment: When I run your code and return the corpus object and call `gsub2`, I get `A corpus with 4 text documents`. What do you mean by "R fails to recognize the corpus object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you, as you already suggested, return the `corpus` object?

```
gsub2<- function(myPattern, myReplacement, myCorpus, fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=FALSE){
  for (i in 1:length(myCorpus)){
    for (j in 1:length(myPattern)){
      myCorpus[[i]]<- gsub(myPattern[j],myReplacement[j], myCorpus[[i]], fixed=TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(myCorpus)
}
```

and then

```
a <- gsub2(pattern1,replacement1,corpus,fixed=TRUE)

 > class(a)
[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus"  "list"   


> for (i in 1:length(a)){print(a[[i]])}
this is a gameOne
this is gameTwo
this is gameThree
this is testFour
```

Is this not what you want?

Comment: Ah, yes! The error message I mentioned was that of an unexpected symbol, which, as I now figured, was because I was using the wrong type of brackets to return myCorpus. Which is embarrassing...
But thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `mapply`:

```
# original data
corpus <- c("this is a testOne","this is testTwo","this is testThree","this is testFour")
# make a copy to gsub into
corpus2 <- corpus

# set pattern/replacement
pattern1<- c("testOne","testTwo","testThree")
replacement1<- c("gameOne","gameTwo","gameThree")

corpus2 # before gsub
# run gsub on all of the patterns/replacements
x <- mapply(FUN= function(...) {
     corpus2 <<- gsub(...,x=corpus2)},
     pattern=pattern1, replacement=replacement1)
rm(x) # discard x; it's empty
corpus2 # after gsub
```

Comment: This is a good and simple alternative approach. I understand that this will be less computationally expensive than my function.
Thanks.